# Select rows in Orange based on column value comparison

Tags: preprocessing, orange

I'm trying to remove some rows from a cardio dataset where the value for the systolic pressure (ap_hi) is below the diastolic pressure (ap_low) which to me indicates a data error.  The code I would use in Python is

`df.drop(df[(df['ap_lo'] > df['ap_hi'])].index,inplace=True)`

But the Select Row widget in Orange only allows selection for numeric features based on a numeric value, not comparison with another feature.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!